# mpiexec error 10061 Connect on sock failed

Tags: c, mpi, mpiexec

I have a problem:

**mpiexec.exe -noprompt  -wdir "D:\###" -n 1 "D:\###\_simple_test.exe"**

prints

**Error while connecting to host, ###. (10061)**

**Connect on sock (host=###-pc, port=8678) failed, exhaused all end points**

**Unable to connect to '###-pc:8678',**

**sock error: Error = -1**

Code of program:

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <mpi.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char message[20];
    int i, rank, size, type = 99;
    MPI_Status status;
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    if (rank == 0)
    {
        strcpy(message, "Hello, world!");
        for (i = 1; i < size; i++)
            MPI_Send(message, 14, MPI_CHAR, i, type,
                MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }
    else
        MPI_Recv(message, 20, MPI_CHAR, 0, type,
            MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
    printf("Message from process = %d : %.14s\n", rank, message);
    MPI_Finalize();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: This is what I get when I execute your program, looks to be working - check your mpi installation. How did you 


$ mpirun -n 1 ./a.out
Message from process = 0 : Hello, world!compile your program?




$ mpirun -n 4 ./a.out
Message from process = 0 : Hello, world!
Message from process = 1 : Hello, world!
Message from process = 2 : Hello, world!
Message from process = 3 : Hello, world!

Comment: This is likely an installation issue. To get any help on that you need to clearly describe how you installed with MPI implementation and what your host setup is.